# Which can be used delimiters in Netezza database

Tags: java, netezza

I am trying to insert file into netezza database so I need help which character can we use as delimiters. I was trying these are delimiters.

```
'|'  ','  ';'  '~'  '^'
```

But user does not accept it because they are using under sentence.

Answer (score 0):

If you  mean you are trying to load data in Netezza database , then you can use any of the delimiters. This mostly depends how you are handling that via nzload or via some other application. Assuming you are using java(as you tagged java) you can use all the tags '|'  ','  ';'  '~'  '^'.

Answer (score 0):

One thing can't be two things.

You can't have "|" be your column delimiter and also use the | within your text strings.  How is the system supposed to recognize when to accept it as text ... and when it is meant to separate two columns.

Options:
You can use that symbol (or any symbol for that matter) as long as you escape it within the text strings.  For example

123|The pipe | symbol is here|456

You could use any non-printing ascii character as the delimiter.  This greatly reduces the likelihood of ever encountering it in an input text string.

You could specify it thusly

```
 nzload -delim 0xc7   ...           # the hexadecimal value
 nzload -delim 199    ...           # or in decimal
 nzload -delim 0307   ...           # or in octal
```